# Could not find method complie() for arguments whilst adding recyclerView dependency

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to add a dependency so I can use RecyclerView.

In andriod studio I went to build > edit libraries and dependencies. Then searched for Recycler in the choose library dependency. I found the library below.

```
com.android.support:recyclerview-v7 (com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1)
```

After adding this though the gradle could not build. I read on here that it was due to the version and that is should be changed to 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'.

However now I am getting a different error message which I don't follow,

```
Error:(30, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
```

> Could not find method complie() for arguments [com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

**gradle**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.xxx.yyyyyyyyy"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
   }
 }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    complie 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
}
```

**manifest**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could not find method complie()

There is a small typo in your `dependencies`

Change:

```
complie 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
```

with:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `complie` instead of `compile`.